# Extend ProjectionViewer to hide line by regex

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-cdt

Is there a point in ProjectionViewer of Eclipse CDT to fold single lines instead of blocks like in the example below?

---

```
1: int main(){
2:     call_regex();
3:     return 1;
4: }
```

After activated "Hide Button":

```
1: int main(){
3:     return 1;
4: }
```

Deactivate "Hide Button":

```
1: int main(){
2:     call_regex();
3:     return 1;
4: }
```

Comment: Have you managed to get the projection viewer to work outside of CDT, i.e. just on a simple text editor (like the one the new project wizard creates)?

Comment: Yes I have managed to create and load my own editor :) but now I am strugglin with projectionviewer :(

Comment: @JonahGraham my editor extends the CEditor and replaces AdaptedSourceViewer with my custom one which relies on CSourceViewer, I don't know where I should get into code there...

Comment: I am not quite sure where you are. Do you have projections working as you desire, but what to integrate that into CEditor, or do you need to figure out how to use the projections? I suspect it is the latter, if so, please review https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Folding-in-Eclipse-Text-Editors/folding.html . Remember, you decide the structure to "fold" on, i.e. don't be limited to what the existing folding providers have done. Short of writing a full starting point for you on this, I am not sure I can really answer the question. If I have misunderstood, please let me know.

Comment: My problem is that I have to copy paste so much stuff of CEditor, because there is so much private stuff I can't import that I have over 1000 lines in my custom editor without writing a single one by myself. There I should then add my CustomSourceViewer instead of AdaptedSourceViewer. So my problem is that I want to preserve the functionallity of CEditor and also where to enter into ProjectionViewer.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some refactoring of CEditor and provide some submissions back to CDT. Please do that! The community will benefit. In the meantime, you make a copy of the CEditor into your plugin, refactor it there and write your editor to extend it. That way you can start shipping your plug-in even before all your changes make it back to the CEditor upstream.